# Angular - CDN reference works, local min file does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML file with some Javascript in it. I'm using Angular.js. If I reference the CDN, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

everything works fine. If I try to use a local angular.js or angular.min.js file, the Angular functions break:

```
<script src="../Javascript/angular.js"></script>
```

Is there a known reason for this? Nothing else changes. My problem is that I'm not sure if my code can get to the CDN where I'm deploying it. The Angular functions aren't working in the deployment location with the CDN reference, and I want to test with the local reference, but I can't get it working in dev in the first place.

Comment: Should work fine either way.  First thing I'd check in the debugger is whether your local file is being loaded or do you see an error loading it.

Comment: Is the path correct relative to the html file

Comment: Is your local one angular.min.js rather than angular.js?

Comment: @megawac - yes, it's the correct path.

Comment: @ZackArgyle - I've tried both. I know the min is the correct one to use when deploying, but I'm just testing in dev and neither one will work.

Comment: This is a hack, but you could download the CDN version and use that locally

Comment: sounds like you are using different version numbers

Comment: @charlietfl - the version number for the CDN and the most recent download should match, right?

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of angular from here <kbd>[Download](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/archive/master.zip)</kbd>

And include  Angular.js file in head tag

> `<src href="path/to/angular.js" ></script>`

To check file loaded or not go to console (F12) and click on network .

I hope this may help you .

Download latest version of angular from here <kbd>[Download](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/archive/master.zip)</kbd>